# How to change the return type to "string" and just return the view name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a helper class where I am checking some condition and if it is true return to viewpage1 else viewpage2.

In the if/else statements I have used HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect which will redirect the user. However, the method is expecting to return a model. There will never be a return if redirect in the middle of the method. Instead, I think need to change the return type to "string" and just return the view name. How do I do that?

Helper Class :

```
    public static OperationResult RetrievemData(customerViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var sqlStatement = @"select * from customertable where last_name=@last_name ";
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_LIB_CONNECTION_STRING"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@last_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.LastName;
                    using (var sqlResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (sqlResult.HasRows)
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/ViewPage1");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/ViewPage2");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error was encountered. " + e);
        }

        return model;
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Getdata(customerViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var keyvalue = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Session["Appkey"]);
        long temp;
        bool success = Int64.TryParse((HttpContext.Request.QueryString["keyvalue"]), out temp);
        if (success)
        {
            return View(CustomerViewHelper.RetrievemData(model));

        }
        else
        {
            return View(CustomerViewHelper.SpecificData(keyvalue));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not make it a `void` function and not return anything?

Comment: I think that works. But I have one more problem. If I make it void how do I call the helper class in contoller. Sorry I missed to add the contoller part earlier. I added the contoller code.

Comment: If I make the helper class void and return nothing controller gives error 'the best overloaded method for 'system.web.mvc.contoller.view(system.web.mvc.IView) has some invalid arguments'

Comment: You'd probably just want to call the function as is (you can't pass it into anything because by definition is void). The following should work: `if(success) { CustomerViewHelper.RetrievemData(model); } return View(CustomerViewHelper.SpecificData(keyvalue));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string RetrievemData(customerViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var sqlStatement = @"select * from customertable where last_name=@last_name ";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_LIB_CONNECTION_STRING"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@last_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.LastName;
                using (var sqlResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return sqlResult.HasRows ? "~/ViewPage1" : "~/ViewPage2";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("An error was encountered. " + e);
    }
}
```